# one static variable to multiple copies

Tags: c++, c, variables, static

Is there a way to have a static variable have multiple copies in C/C++?

The following code have a static variable - miles. How to achieve that runner1() and runner2() have its own miles copy but keep miles as static?

test.h

```
static int miles;
extern int get_miles();
```

test.c

```
#include "test.h"

int get_miles() {
   miles = miles + 1;
   return miles;
}
```

user.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

extern void runner1();
extern void runner2();

void runner1() {
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
      printf("runner1 runs %0d miles\n", get_miles());
   }
}

void runner2() {
   int j;
   for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
      printf("runner2 runs %0d miles\n", get_miles());
   }
}

int main() {
  runner1();
  runner2();
}
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3G7h

Comment: You'd have to put `runner1()` and `runner2()` in separate files, and each would need their own `get_miles()` too (in the same file).  But it feels like there's an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here.  Why are you trying to do this?  It looks at least somewhat absurd.  (Incidentally, `%0d` may as well be `%d`.)  Also, you should really choose one of the two languages: there are options available in C++ that aren't a part of C.

Comment: Use two functions, get_miles1() and get_miles2(), and two static counters.

Comment: You can't have two different values in one `static` variable at the same time.

Comment: So... you want the same function `get_miles()`, with no arguments, to do different things when called from `runner2` than when called from `runner1`?

Comment: This is going to be really fragile code that breaks easily.  Declaring a static in a .h file is an extremely bad idea.  The point of .h files is to give .c files a reliable way to guarantee that they all agree on common symbols.  It's where extern definitions go; static definitions (which are by their nature local to the .c file) belong in the .c files.

I do not understand why you want to keep miles as a global of any sort when you have routines for each runner; nor why you want that variable to be static.  Why not just print i and j in runner1()/runner2()?

Modular coding makes life easy

Answer (score 0):

This is contradictory: You want two things that are different and  equal at the same time.